# Given a list of numbers, find the minimum number of swaps required so that no two adjacent elements are same

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This question is asked in Google onsite interview. [Link](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/1304006/Google-or-Onsite-Interview-or-Form-the-sequence-of-team-members)

I was able to come up with a brute-force solution where I'll enumerate over all `n!` arrangements and of all the valid arrangements, I'll calculate the minimum of the swaps required for that arrangement.

```
class Solution{
private:
    bool check(const string&str){
        return (adjacent_find(begin(str),end(str))==end(str));
    }
public:
    void minimumSwaps(string &str,int &ansSwaps,int swaps=0,int idx=0)
    {
        if(check(str)){
            ansSwaps=min(ansSwaps,swaps);
        }
        for(int i=idx;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++)
            {
                swap(str[i],str[j]);
                minimumSwaps(str,ansSwaps,swaps+1,i+1);
                swap(str[i],str[j]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Since this question is asked in an interview, I'm assuming this to have a better time complex solution in form of greedy or graph related concepts but couldn't up with anything.

Discussion on codeforces : https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53781

Comment: What are you exactly looking for here?

Comment: The post title entered is already solved by the shared code. The text `assuming this has a better time complex solution.. ` sounds more like a statement than a question (at least to me).. mind rephrasing your intent/worries/[code-review-request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317404/what-is-the-policy-concerning-interview-questions)

Comment: @p._phidot_ it is not solved for the same reason a brute force algorithm doesn't solve the factoring problem. It should not be sent to [codereview.se] for the same reason a brute force algorithm that "solves" the factoring problem should not be sent to [codereview.se]. The only review you are likely to get there is "throw this stuff away and come back when you have a real solution".